# Find actual type of a method parameter in macro

Tags: scala, scala-macros

Suppose I have a macro implementation

```
def testImpl[T](c:Context)(implicit wtt:c.WeakTypeTag[T]):c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._

    def info(msg: Any) = c.info(c.enclosingPosition, msg.toString, true)

    val parameter = wtt.tpe.member(TermName("f")).paramLists(0)(0)

    info(parameter.typeSignature)

    q"{}"
}
```

And a macro definition

```
def test[T]:Unit = macro DerivingImpl.testImpl[T]
```

This macro finds function `f` in its type parameter, and prints information about its first parameter's type.

Now if I use this macro like this

```
trait Trait[A] {
    def f(x:A): Int
}

test[Trait[Int]]
```

I get `A` printed. I would like to get `Int`. I understand that calling `member` returns the method symbol which does not have information about the concrete applied type. So, what is the correct way to find the actual type of the parameter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val f = wtt.tpe.member(TermName("f"))
val MethodType(parameter :: Nil, _) = f.typeSignatureIn(wtt.tpe)
info(parameter.typeSignature)
```